# How to display the Reviews section of my database

Tags: java, firebase-realtime-database

I have tried to reorganised my database by adding a child called ("Reviews") that should include reviews added by the users but I keep getting a null displayed on the screen. I can only assume that the variables have not been saved into my modal class. I thought that my calling getReview() in my modal class should work:

```
     DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(); // getReference() is the root
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list.clear();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {


                    Information info = snapshot.getValue(Information.class);
                    assert info != null;

                    String txt = "Medical Clinic: " + info.getName() + " \n\n " + "Review: " + info.getReview() + "\n\nServices Provided: " + info.getDorevitch() + " : " + info.getSkin_Cancer() + " : " + info.getEar_Suctioning();
                    list.add(txt);

  //      list.add(snapshot.getValue().toString());
                }

                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

             This is my modal class

    enter code hepublic class Information {    // variables have to match in firebase database or it will show null
    private String Address;
    private String Name;
    private String Phone_No;
    private String Suburb;
    private String State;
    private String Postcode;
    private String Doctor;
    private String Dorevitch;
    private String Skin_Cancer;
    private String Ear_Suctioning;

    private String Reviews;

    public Information() {
    }

    public Information(String address, String name, String phone_No, String suburb, String state, String postcode, String dorevitch, String skin_cancer, String ear_suctioning, String doctor, String review) {
        Address = address;
        Name = name;
        Phone_No = phone_No;
        Suburb = suburb;
        State = state;
        Postcode = postcode;
        Doctor = doctor;
        Dorevitch = dorevitch;
        Skin_Cancer = skin_cancer;
        Ear_Suctioning = ear_suctioning;
        Reviews = review;
    }

    public String getDorevitch() {
        return Dorevitch;
    }

    public void setDorevitch(String dorevitch) {
        Dorevitch = dorevitch;
    }

    public String getSkin_Cancer() {
        return Skin_Cancer;
    }

    public void setSkin_Cancer(String skin_Cancer) {
        Skin_Cancer = skin_Cancer;
    }

    public String getEar_Suctioning() {
        return Ear_Suctioning;
    }

    public void setEar_Suctioning(String ear_Suctioning) {
        Ear_Suctioning = ear_Suctioning;
    }

    public String getState() {
        return State;
    }

    public void setState(String state) {
        State = state;
    }

    public String getDoctor() {
        return Doctor;
    }

    public void setDoctor(String doctor) {
        Doctor = doctor;
    }

    public String getSuburb() {
        return Suburb;
    }

    public void setSuburb(String suburb) {
        Suburb = suburb;
    }

    public String getReview() {
        return Reviews;
    }

    public void setReview(String review) {
        Reviews = review;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return Address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        Address = address;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        Name = name;
    }

    public String getPhone_No() {
        return Phone_No;
    }

    public void setPhone_No(String phone_No) {
        Phone_No = phone_No;
    }

    public String getPostcode() {
        return Postcode;
    }

    public void setPostcode(String postcode) {
        Postcode = postcode;
    }
```

[image]

[image]

I can get it to work but don't know why it is only working if I pull out from the database by doing the following code and not using my modal class?

String reviews = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Reviews").getValue());
String services = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Services").getValue());

What is the difference between String.valueof and toString()?

Comment: For some reason, if I do this, then it works

Comment: tring reviews = String.valueOf(snapshot.child("Reviews").getValue());

                        String txt = "Medical Clinic: " + info.getName() + " \n\n " + "Review: " + reviews + "\n\nServices Provided: " + info.getDorevitch() + " : " + info.getSkin_Cancer() + " : " + info.getEar_Suctioning();

Comment: So, when would I be using my modal class instead of pulling data from the database??

Comment: If you have information to add to your question, you're supposed to edit the question with the edit link, not add comments.

Comment: apologies... will do that

Comment: I think the problem is with using hashmap... always seem to be a convert to string issue...